# Java 17: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException with Add opens in manifest

Tags: java, java-17

I'm trying to migrate an application from java 11 to java 17.

I have a war build via maven with Java 17. It has a transitive dependencies to kryo (2.23) and kryo serializers 0.42. There is a known compatibility issue with java 17: https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers/issues/131

To summarize it goes like this  kryo <- library(internal) <- war

I thought  that adding Add-opens to the manifest of my war would solve the issue.

```
Add-Opens: java.base/java.lang java.base/java.util
```

Sadly, when I try to start the application (tomcat-9.0.24) I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @726825d9
at de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.ArraysAsListSerializer.<init>(ArraysAsListSerializer.java:47)
```

I checked the manifest in the war and it seems ok:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.8.6
Built-By: XXX
Build-Jdk: 17.0.3
Class-Path: ...
...
Add-Opens: java.base/java.lang java.base/java.util
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not a correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: The JEP-261 spec says. "These attributes are interpreted only in the main executable JAR file of an application, i.e., in the JAR file specified to the -jar option of the Java run-time launcher; they are ignored in all other JAR files.". So, I guess it doesn't work in a .war

Comment: Thanks. maybe it's the answer. I already have a working solution by adding --add-opens in jvm options but if it had worked in the manifest it would be more convenient.

Comment: I think Tomcat is the "application", not the WebApp in the .war file